# Is it vaild to put the "numOwners" to more than 1 in Infinispan when shared JDBC cache store is in place?

Tags: java, caching, infinispan, distributed-cache, infinispan-8

We have a 5 node cluster with a shared JDBC cache store(DB is common for all the nodes). However, when I put the "numOwners" setting to more than 1 , the writes to the cache and DB are failing with primary key exceptions. I expected that only one node would write the updates to the store but that's not happening. If I put the "numOwners" to 1 then everything is working fine but then it's not really adistribute mode. Am I missing anything? Please help.

Comment: have you configured the cache stores as shared? 
See http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#configuration_2 (shared attribute)

Comment: @pruivo Yes, of course.

Answer (score 2):

According to intended design, you are correct. It should be valid to have numOwners >= 1 even with a shared CacheStore.

Please raise an issue.